# A Golang Worker Pool, where the workers themselves open and close the SQL Connections

Tags: mysql, go, concurrency, pool, worker

i was experimenting with Go worker pools to speed up my import script with concurrent workers. But without any luck by now. And i spend lot of hours until i wrote this post...

First i used this one https://github.com/gammazero/workerpool, which worked out very well in first place. But the problem here, is that i submit Jobs to some 'pool' and these jobs are executed. When i try write to the same SQL Table at the same time from all jobs, i get some Segmentation fault after random amount of time. Then i got the advice to open a new sql connection per worker. And that is by design not possible with the upper library, as i have no control about the workers themselves.

Then i tried the code from here https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools and entered the SQL Open and Close at the top and the bottom of the worker() for-range. But i had no luck. Although i pushed 1000s of jobs to the Pool, only 16 jobs where taken (1 by each worker, with 16 workers) and stop. And i have no clue why.

Could anyone of you provide me a solid example code about a golang worker pool, where each worker controls the SQL Connection ?

By the way, i use https://gorm.io as MySQL ORM, which works out very well up to this point.

Maybe anyone of you could help me. I can also provide you with further details.
That would speed up my import script massively.

Bye then
Adrian

Comment: "And that is by design not possible with the upper library, as i have no control about the workers themselves." how so? You have total control over the workers themselves, the entire body of the worker is your code.

Comment: How did you organize the connection pool to the database? https://go.dev/doc/database/manage-connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found out, that the opening and closing of the mysql connection didnt cause the segfault. it was rather the data inside some of the products. after adding a defer func to recover from segfaults everyting is running smoothly.